# jQuery hover function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a hover effect using jQuery and data-attribute.

So what I did is that I put some data attribute on each images and then I access them via jQuery and store them in a variable. Then I access them to change the image via jQuery. However, I have no idea how to put it back to the original on "mouseout"

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').hover(function(){
        var s = $(this).attr('data-alt-src');
        $(this).attr('src', s);
    }, function(){
        $(this).attr('src');
    });
});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store current src as a variable and use it

```
   var old="";
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('img').hover(function(){
            old=$(this).attr('src');
            var s = $(this).attr('data-alt-src');
            $(this).attr('src', s);
        }, function(){
            $(this).attr('src',old);
        });
    });
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzxh1asx/5/)**

Comment: Can I ask a question? Why can't we declare the var old inside the $(document).ready(function(){} ???

Answer (score 2):

try to set origional src to other attribute and use that when mouseleave.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').hover(function(){
        var s = $(this).attr('data-alt-src');            
        $(this).attr('orSrc',$(this).attr('src')).attr('src', s);
    }, function(){
        $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('orSrc'));
    });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jzxh1asx/3/)

Comment: Can I ask a question? Why can't we declare the var old inside the $(document).ready(function(){} ??? ABOVE THE var old src. ??? –  Kimberly Wright

Comment: Can you explain further why?

Comment: what will happen if I will declare these whole thing above the hover function: var original_src=$(this).attr('src'); would it still be accessible on mouse out?

Comment: not at all because `$(this)` refers to hoved image(i.e which image being hoved) so it will throw an error

Answer (score 1):

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var src_original;
      $('img').hover(function() {
        src_original = $(this).attr('src');
        var s = $(this).attr('data-alt-src');
        $(this).attr('src', s);
      }, function() {
        $(this).attr('src', src_original);
      });
    });
```

```css
img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <img src="http://goo.gl/osWLNm" data-alt-src='http://goo.gl/K5yFHa' />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/umj4bX" data-alt-src='http://goo.gl/bz4jQH' />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/W1fumF" data-alt-src='http://goo.gl/d4gynn' />
  <img src="http://goo.gl/wMb04Z" data-alt-src='http://goo.gl/LqZU0Q' />

</section>
```

Comment: Can I ask a question? Why can't we declare the var old inside the $(document).ready(function(){} ???  ABOVE THE var old src. ???

Comment: @KimberlyWright It is declared in inside DOM ready, but if you are asking about why not inside `hover` function it won't be available for `mouseout` function, since it is a local variable.

Comment: so we need to declare it as an empty variable outside the hover function first and then set a value on it inside the hover function am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Store original image `src` in cache using `.data()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').hover(function () {
        var that = $(this);
        that.data('or-src', that.prop('src'))
        that.prop('src', that.data('alt-src'));
    }, function () {
        var that = $(this);
        $(this).prop('src', that.data('or-src'));
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/tmkegrgp/)

Answer (score 0):

I added data-old-src to store default img source and load on mouse out.

Check https://jsfiddle.net/jzxh1asx/6/

HTML

```
  <section>
    <img src="http://goo.gl/osWLNm" data-old-src="http://goo.gl/osWLNm" data-alt-src='http://goo.gl/K5yFHa' />
    <img src="http://goo.gl/umj4bX" data-old-src="http://goo.gl/umj4bX" data-alt-src='http://goo.gl/bz4jQH' />
    <img src="http://goo.gl/W1fumF" data-old-src="http://goo.gl/W1fumF" data-alt-src='http://goo.gl/d4gynn' />
    <img src="http://goo.gl/wMb04Z" data-old-src="http://goo.gl/wMb04Z" data-alt-src='http://goo.gl/LqZU0Q' />
  </section>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').hover(function(){
        var s = $(this).attr('data-alt-src');
        $(this).attr('src', s);
    }, function(){
        var os = $(this).attr('data-old-src');
        $(this).attr('src', os);
    });
});
```